# What does " 孤立していて察しのいい" mean?

Tags: translation

[image]

I know what each word means, but when put together as a sentence, I have trouble parsing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a full sentence but a relative clause that modifies シンシャ. の after 察し indicates this is a relative clause. 察しがいい means "perceptive/insightful".

> ……そうだな、孤立していて察しのいいシンシャなら...
>
> Let's see...if (I choose) シンシャ, who is isolated and perceptive, ...